# Native base component's theme is not updating when the theme changes of the App

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I am using native base + react-navigation in an app and need to change the theme of the app. As soon as I change the theme the react-navigation update that easily but the problem is that the native base component theme does not change. It looks odd to the user.

I had used this code to change the theme of the app

```
    <StyleProvider style={getTheme(theme === 'LIGHT' ? platform : material)}>
                <Container>
                    <NavigationContainer
                        theme={theme === 'LIGHT' ? DefaultTheme : MyThemeDark}>
                        <Stack.Navigator
                            initialRouteName={isProfile ? 'Root' : 'Selection'}>
                              ..................

                        </Stack.Navigator>
                    </NavigationContainer>
                </Container>
    </StyleProvider>
```

As I said React navigation theme is updating correctly but the native base theme is not updating.

Comment: You are using Native Base 2, right?
Will it help if there were any solution for Native Base 3?

Comment: Can you please know me how do you managing the theme state?

Comment: At that time, we were not able to solve that bug, so we show one alert to users to "restart the app for the theme to change". And after that, we moved to the Kitten UI

Comment: @AshadNasim I've managed to make it works, it's a bit tricky but it's finally working.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen you can answer this question then, it would help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For native base 3, to change the theme, you can use the React Native hook `useColorScheme` to get the current theme of the device and update the theme using native base method `setColorMode`.

I believe the code needs to be added as child component of `NativeBaseProvider`. For example, may not work in App.js if you define `NativeBaseProvider` there.

```
import React from "react";
import { useColorMode } from 'native-base';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert, useColorScheme } from 'react-native';

export const UseColorMode = () => {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const {
    setColorMode,
  } = useColorMode();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (colorScheme) {
      Alert.alert(`${colorScheme}`)
      setColorMode(colorScheme);
    }
  }, [colorScheme, setColorMode])

  return (<></>)
}
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (<NativeBaseProvider>
    <UseColorMode/>
  </NativeBaseProvider>)
}
```